# Can't insert information to table in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm creating simple java program to manage a garage.
Inside the program you have login window, and afterwards you can register new users.
The problem is that when I want to register new user, after the SELECT query the program is stuck (when the new user isn't in the DB).

I've made sure all connections are closed, made sure I'm using the proper query execution (executeQuery for SELECT and updateQuery for INSERT).

The register class:

```
    class RegisterButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        String username, password;
        String selectUser="";

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
            if (garageView.getTxtNewPassword().getText().isEmpty() == false
                    && garageView.getTxtNewUsername().getText().isEmpty() == false){
                username = garageView.getTxtNewUsername().getText();
                password = garageView.getTxtNewPassword().getText();

                  try {
                     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                     c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:GarageDoctor.db");
                     c.setAutoCommit(false);
                     System.out.println("Opened database successfully - SELECT");

                     stmt=c.createStatement();
                     String selectSql = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME = '"+username+"';";
                     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSql);
                     while(rs.next()) {
                         selectUser+=rs.getString("name");
                         System.out.println(selectUser);
                         if(selectUser.equals(username)) {
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(garageView, "User Already Exists!");
                             System.out.println("closing");
                             selectUser="";
                             rs.close();
                             stmt.close();
                             c.close();
                             System.out.println("closed");
                         }
                         else {    
                               System.out.println("user isn't in db, inserting now");
                               DBInsertNewUsers(username,password);  
                             }
                     }

                  } catch ( Exception e ) {
                     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                     System.exit(0);
                  }

            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(garageView, "Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }
```

Which leads to the DBInsertNewUsers:

```
    public void DBInsertNewUsers(String username,String password) {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:GarageDoctor.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully - Insert");


        stmt = c.createStatement();
        System.out.println("stmt = c.createStatement();");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (ID,PASSWORD,NAME) VALUES ("+i+",'"+password+"', '"+username+"');"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("stmt.executeUpdate(sql);");
        i++;

        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        System.out.println("action done successfully - Insert");
        c.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(garageView, "Register Success");
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
             System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
             System.exit(0);
        }       
    }
```

When trying to register new user the app getting stuck and the last console message is:

```
Opened database successfully - SELECT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME = '"+username+"';
```

will return row(s) only if there exists a row with that username.
Also `rs.next()` in that case is `true` and you enter the loop in which there is an `if` statement for which the condition:

```
selectUser.equals(username)
```

will be for sure `true`.
So the `else` block will never execute.
What you must do is remove the while loop and keep only an if/else block:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (garageView.getTxtNewPassword().getText().isEmpty() == false
            && garageView.getTxtNewUsername().getText().isEmpty() == false) {
        username = garageView.getTxtNewUsername().getText();
        password = garageView.getTxtNewPassword().getText();

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:GarageDoctor.db");
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully - SELECT");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String selectSql = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME = '" + username + "';";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSql);
            boolean exists = rs.next();
            System.out.println("closing");
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
            System.out.println("closed");
            if (exists) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(garageView, "User Already Exists!");
                selectUser = "";
            } else {
                System.out.println("user isn't in db, inserting now");
                DBInsertNewUsers(username, password);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(garageView, "Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Also inside `DBInsertNewUsers()` you are using a variable `i` to set the value for the column `id`.
From the code you posted I can't find how it is initialized and if the column `id` is a Primary Key. 
So this part needs special attention if you want to avoid unsuccessful inserts.
In `DBInsertNewUsers()` change the order of the statements to:

```
c.commit();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the 'i' is static integer, I use it for the incremented ID of the users.
Also, what you've suggested finally made me even go inside the ```DBInsertNewUsers```.
Problem is, I'm getting SQLException: database is locked after the command:
```
stmt.close();
```
Inside the method.

Comment: All objects must be closed before the call to DBInsertNewUsers. See my edited answer.

Comment: I've made sure everything in my code is matching yours (the edited version), yet I still getting the exception..

Comment: Sadly it's still isn't working. The exception occurring while getting to the line:
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
inside DBInsertNewUsers

Comment: Beside console messages, all I get from the Eclipse is:
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! 
The problem for the locking was happened since I used my DB browser *face palm* !

Answer (score 1):

Your code to call DBInsertNewUsers is inside the while(rs.next()) loop. In the case where there are no matching rows, rs.next() will return false (since there are no rows) and control will never enter that loop. You should also consider using the "try-with-resources" pattern for closing your resources and use a prepared statement:

```
String query = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME = ?";
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);) { 
        ps.setString(1,username);
        try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSql);){
             if(rs.next()){
               selectUser+=rs.getString("name");
             }else{
               System.out.println("user isn't in db, inserting now");
               DBInsertNewUsers(username,password);  
             }
        }
}
```